# iOS Static Framework - What to Expose?

Tags: ios, xcode5, static-libraries, ios-frameworks

I'm following the step in this tutorial and I'm not able to access the Widget class unless I also import it before I use it. In the sample project, it works with just importing of the main header file.

https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework#first_parties

Is there another step that I missed out? My main header file is importing the other one and they are both exposed at public level.

Comment: Have you tried clean project and build again?

Comment: It seems like that were 2 issues. For some reasons, the framework.a wasn't added even when I specified target dependency. After adding it, I'm able to build and run. However, even after I clean the project, Xcode still shows compile error even though it's able to build. How do I get rid of the "incorrect" error? It shows that there is no error for a few seconds and then after the build is done, the error shows again.

Comment: what exact error do you get?

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier "Widget". Widget is a class that is imported in the main header.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken import header error sounds different - smth like: "no visible @interface....

Comment: It seems like I may have corrupted the project somehow. If I create a brand new project and import the framework again, there is no issue. Now I just need to figure out what went wrong in case I run into it again.

Comment: Smth pretty easy might be, probably typo error etc. Good luck